# Is there a good JavaScript minifier?

Tags: javascript, minify

What JavaScript minifier do you recommend?

Comment: Have you tried http://dean.edwards.name/packer/?

Comment: Although the question is old and closed, as of 2019 - terser (https://github.com/terser-js/terser) is a fairy good minifier. There's also a plugin for Rollup which is great for minifying bundles on the fly.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

[UglifyJS2](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2), used by the jQuery project.

Comment: You can use UglifyJS online without the need to install it - http://jscompress.com/ . +1 for the product used by jQuery

Comment: is it used more than closure?

Comment: @FutuToad: Current version is [UglifyJS2](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2). I was looking for a comparison of the minifiers and I found the stats here http://lisperator.net/uglifyjs/ - it seems that Google Closure is slower than UglifyJS. However, Closure can minify AngularJS projects. So there is no clear winner. My guess is (after an hour long research) that UglifyJS2 is used more than GC.

Comment: PS: You can try [Minify JS](http://js-minify.online-domain-tools.com/run/?inputType=text&beautify=0&mangle=1&mangleReservedWords=myLastName&text=var+hello+%3D+function%28myFirstName%2C+myLastName%29+%7B%0D%0A++alert%28%22Hello+%22+%2B+myFirstName+%2B+%27+%27+%2B+myLastName%29%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0Ahello%28%22John%22%2C+%22Smith%22%29%3B)  that is based on UglifyJS2 and your source codes won't be sent to a remote server. ;)

Comment: Does UglifyJS support es6? all tools I've found throw's errors since I use a lot of es6 functionality in my files.

Comment: @MartinVseticka It seemed to have minified my code to a smaller size than closure compiler did, on top of that, it had more readability and kept whitespace. Thanks for showing me Minify JS.

Answer (score 33):

### Active

- [Closure Compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/)
- [UglifyJS2](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2)

### Deprecated

- [YUI Compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/)
- [UglifyJS](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS/)

---

Google Closure Compiler generally achieves smaller files than YUI Compressor, particularly if you use the advanced mode, which looks worryingly meddlesome to me but has worked well on the one project I've used it on:

Several big projects use UglifyJS, and I've been very impressed with it since switching.

Comment: Google CC simple mode also achieves smaller size than YUI, and it's safe as well

Answer (score 12):

[JavaScript Minifier](http://javascript-minifier.com) gives a good API you can use programatically:

```
curl -X POST -s --data-urlencode 'input=$(function() { alert("Hello, World!"); });' http://javascript-minifier.com/raw
```

Or by uploading a file and redirecting to a new file:

```
curl -X POST -s --data-urlencode 'input@ready.js' http://javascript-minifier.com/raw > ready.min.js
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 10):

If you are using PHP you might also want to take a look at [minify](http://code.google.com/p/minify/) which can minify and combine JavaScript files. The integration is pretty easy and can be done by defined groups of files or an easy query string. Minified files are also cached to reduce the server load and you can add expire headers through minify.

Answer (score 9):

There are several you can use/try:

- [YUI compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/)
- [jsmin](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/jsmin.html)
- [Microsoft Ajax minifier](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxMinDocumentation.ashx) (has hypercrunching)

Comment: What is hypercrunching? This is what I got on the subject: https://ajaxmin.codeplex.com/discussions/260683

Comment: @EhteshChoudhury It means that the minifier gets even more aggressive about it. It takes out unused code and shortens also the names of local variables.

Answer (score 7):

Pretty Diff - http://prettydiff.com/?m=minify

Comment: I gotta say that this is by far the best online tool as some of the others crap out when you give them anything over 8000 lines to minify.

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes i use this: http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home

Answer (score 4):

This tool: [jscompressor.com](https://jscompressor.com) is pretty good.

Comment: The website is offline.

Comment: Thank you. It's work with me. This is the best website I have ever used for minify Javascript

Answer (score 2):

[YUI minifier](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/)