# JavaScript Minifier

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-framework, minify, packer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Searching a good Javascript Minifier.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520285/searching-a-good-javascript-minifier)

I am working on several javascript files that I would like to minify, but *not* pack. What is the **best** minifier out there? Personally, I'd like to find one that:

1. Is used by reliable JavaScript frameworks, such as jQuery.
2. Doesn't keep your code. :)

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Why the downvotes? Granted 'best' is subjective, but hardly a bad question.

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering the same thing.

Comment: This question has been answered ***several*** times before

Comment: @Mutt: agreed. That's why we have 'close as duplicate'. It should be marked as dup, and not downvoted. Funny that none of the votes are for duplicate. The downvotes are bizarre; I guess they're free now, so voters are feeling free!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I often use this "minifier:"

http://fmarcia.info/jsmin/test.html

It has levels of minification, and it's web based, so you don't have to install anything to use it.

Answer (score 1):

This is the one I use. It is an exe you need to download.

http://www.crockford.com/javascript/jsmin.html

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

YUI Compressor is a commonly used tool: http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/.

That link gives you plenty of information about YUI, but for further information about it and other ways to improve loading times, see [this article](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#minify).