# javascript minimizer

Tags: javascript, minify, minimize

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a good JavaScript minimizer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520285/is-there-a-good-javascript-minimizer)

i'm looking for javascript minimizer , not a regular one that get out the namespaces , i talk about something to short my variables names , function names and so on , that can face scoping and match the variables by the scope , what i looking from the minimizer is :

1. get variable names shorter
2. get functions names shorter
3. facing scoping

you can see Jquery mini to know what i mean

is there anything out there that can do that?

Comment: YUICompressor, Google Closure Compiler, etc.

Comment: @Pointy does those compressors have online version?

Comment: http://marijnhaverbeke.nl/uglifyjs

Comment: @Mor Sela: http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home

Comment: I don't think an online version would be very useful - it's the sort of thing that you should do as part of your "build" or deployment, preferably. You certainly would not want to maintain your code in the form it's left in by such tools :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/

Comment: +1 for YUI Compressor.  There's also a .NET port somewhere that can plug right into MS Build..

Answer (score 0):

http://chirpy.codeplex.com/ Chirpy does all sorts of good things to minify your js and css as well as your less files if you use less (which you should def look into if you don't use it).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to minify js online, you can use this http://jscompress.com/