# jqPlot - What tool to use to minify jqPlot JavaScript files

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot

I've made some changes to one of the jqPlot plugin files (`jqplot.highlighter.js`) and I'd like to minify it before deployment.

Does anyone know what tool jqPlot developers use to minify their jqPlot related .js files?  Perhaps they use JSMin?

In `jqplot.json2.js` file I've found:

```
This code should be minified before deployment.
See http://javascript.crockford.com/jsmin.html
```

But I wanted to double check for consistency.

Many thanks

Comment: Maybe if you check out the `jqPlot` forum or groups etc. (http://www.jqplot.com/info.php) you will have more luck getting an answer. Please do share it if you receive a satisfactory answer. Cheers.

Comment: @Boro Thanks for your suggestion.  I've got an answer from Google jqPlot group.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a good JavaScript minifier?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520285/is-there-a-good-javascript-minifier)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Minifying jqPlot files was more involved than I initially thought.

Here is how: [How to properly minify jqPlot files](https://groups.google.com/group/jqplot-users/browse_thread/thread/5afa9b238f67da2d)