# Javascript dictionary of syntax (standard functions, objects, methods, and keywords)

Tags: javascript, syntax, dictionary

**Where can I find a comprehensive dictionary of all the default javascript keywords and function/method/member names?**

Some of the places I found:

- I have Notepad++, so my first idea was to just extract all the auto-fill words from the javascript xml. It's what I have currently, but it's not comprehensive.
- Then I remembered that Chrome's js console also has auto-fill, and it's certainly pretty comprehensive (it also includes user-defined stuff, but not on a completely blank page). The only problem is, how do I find where the default js setup for Chrome is cached?

Notes: I was also thinking, maybe there's a comprehensive online dictionary or something. Also, even if it's not a perfect csv of all the words, I can always write a quick filter program to properly format it. Lastly, it doesn't need to be so comprehensive as to include every word and every vendor-specific function/object name - it's mostly for personal use, and therefore isn't vital for it to be constantly accurate and up-to-date, etc.

Comment: Sounds like the wrong approach to me. What you can compress are *local* variable names and *module-scope* (not exposed) property names. Everything that is global or implements an interface which you don't control is incompressible. "keywords" or "common names" won't help you.

Comment: Btw, why do you want to reinvent the wheel? Or is this just for learning purposes?

Comment: making javascript as concise as possible, if I understand correctly, both optimizes and obfuscates code. I see it in popular libraries (e.g. JQuery).

Comment: @Bergi, I see what you're saying: I'm trying to _avoid_ compressing standard global variables/functions/objects etc. If I don't have a library of these keywords, my program will take them as user-defined - which *won't* work.

Comment: Shouldn't it work the other way round? Everything that is declared (as local [or global]) in one of the files is user-defined and the rest ist taken implicitly as global.

Comment: The idea is to take arbitrary javascript code, find all user-defined names, and replace all occurences of each with a unique random group of upper and lowercase characters (that's not exactly how it works, but it's the idea). I can't be spending a ton of time logging every variable name, function, or object I create.

Comment: Why "log" every variable? They're in your code already.

Comment: I'm not about to _parse_ complex javascript syntax _just_ to see what variables, functions, and objects are declared. Plus, what happens if I decide to declare a 'getElemenyById' in my own object? Then all other references get replaced, unless I go as far as parsing the javascript *scope*!
I know what I'm doing, and I didn't provide the task so people would argue about it - I provide it to give a reason why what I'm asking for is relevant, and also to help narrow the scope of exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: Well, if you're not doing it properly you better should not do it at all. Parsing the syntax (which is not *that* complex) is essential to the task, otherwise you won't be able to differentiate variable/property names and, say, string literals. Better choose an [existing solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520285/is-there-a-good-javascript-minifier)

Comment: Listen: I'm doing this with php - so only basic is necessary; I'm skipping over strings, regular expressions, comments, and other wrappers - accounting for escape characters; all I need is a dictionary. That's my question; if you don't like it, don't bother answering it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Mozilla Developer Network is a great place for JS documentation.

They have a greatly written wiki with thousands of articles for almostly everything, even some documentation for the upcoming ECMAScript 6.

See:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/DOM_Reference

Comment: There are also a few [reserved keywords](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words) that the above reference link doesn't have, so don't forget to look over these as well if you need to watch for keywords.

Comment: It's referenced as the Appendix A

Comment: I'm not so much looking for a _reference_ as I am just a list - This page would help if everything were listed on the page. That is, I don't see 'window', 'console', etc.

Comment: Thanks! I can use it, but it still doesn't seem to be ... _comprehensive_ - I'm still not seeing 'window' or 'console'

Comment: [Window](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window) is there, under HTML Interfaces. And `console` is a property of `window` in the browser, as well much other common things you could mention ;)