# Remove extra code from JavaScript & JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, jquery-mobile

I have created a website with jQuery.

Now I want to remove extra code from my .js file to reduce the burden on my website.

How do I do that?

I tried brute force approach but it seems tedious.

Comment: You do that by cutting out the bits you don't need. Which bits are they? I don't know - you posted no code. Good luck!

Comment: I'm not aware of any tools to do this automatically.

Comment: SO isn't a requests site, it's a help/advice/guidance site..you can ask about cleaning up a certain function, but we're not going to help you fix all of your code.

Comment: any kind of web site. i have use just hide function from .js file so all another data is not important for me.

Comment: @IlanBiala Bad comment. 
I don't think the OP was asking us to do that. He was asking how to go about cleaning up his own code, without manually finding every unused function, etc.

Comment: "brute force" approach is tedious but you will learn much from it.

Comment: You might be able to upgrade jquery to 2.0 or use Zepto as a jquery alternative depending on what you are doing with you site.

Comment: @Jonathon Reinhart: yes sir i want exactly u told

Comment: @JonathonReinhart a simple google search could've answered this question..Check out the about page of SO http://stackoverflow.com/about and scroll down to the "Get answers to practical, detailed questions" to see the problem with this question.

Comment: @IlanBiala Thanks, I'm quite familiar with the contents of that page, as I've linked to it in many comments. I'm just saying that your comment implies that the OP is asking us *to* clean up his code, when in fact he's asking us *how to* clean up his *own* code.  Sure, he should have searched better, but he's obviously not a native English speaker, and finding the right search terms can be difficult. Don't degrade him for asking for help (on how to help himself).

Comment: @ Jonathon Reinhart: thank you sir for understanding my problems.

Answer (score 1):

Some tips:

- [Use chaining](http://tobiasahlin.com/blog/quick-guide-chaining-in-jquery/)
- [Modularise code](http://www.joezimjs.com/javascript/javascript-closures-and-the-module-pattern/)
- [Minify js files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520285/is-there-a-good-javascript-minifier)

Comment: using minify we can just remove white space,new line & commentes but how about that code which will never going to use in whole web site.

Comment: @Pulah Try profiling your script and see which functions have 0 run count.

Comment: Ok let me see that i just heard about profiling. hope this will work.

Comment: hey frds still profiling is also tedious to work<br/>
& all .js files which are meant to use in jQuery is highly dependent so cannot find its profiling.