# How to save Bootstrap components as self-sufficient code snippets?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap documentation offers only HTML code of components. Even if implement only one component, one is forced to request both of `bootstrap.min.css` and `bootstrap.bundle.min.js`.

Is there any possibility to get Bootstrap component as HTML and only corresponding CSS and JS code? Something like:

```
<script>...</script>
<style>...</style>
<div class="accordion">...</div>
```

How would you achieve this?

Comment: Please tag your Bootstrap version.

Comment: Are you asking about _saving_ or _loading_? Does this answer your question? [Separately loading in Bootstrap components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20666420/separately-loading-in-bootstrap-components)