# How can I minify Javascript files larger than 100MB?

Tags: javascript, html, webgl, minify, unreal-engine4

I'm currently working in Unreal Engine 4 to create interactive HTML5 experiences. The files that UE4 spits out are well over 100MB and whenever I try to minify them using various plugins for Visual Studio or GitHub Atom my editor crashes. Does anyone know of a tool online or local that will minify such large files?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Tried any of these? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520285/is-there-a-good-javascript-minifier

Comment: Is it 100mb of JS code or are the textures in there too?

Comment: Dont know why someone downvoted this question. It is valid!

Comment: @EntityBlack Unfortunately this question is not suited for the SO guidelines. It asks for a tool.

Comment: @Bram Vanroy sad but true :( I though users want to mark it as duplicate.

Comment: You won't ever be able to compress it enough to make something that isn't a game or some app people are okay downloading dozens, or hundreds of MB for. And if you have a loading screen anyway, it doesn't matter that much if it's 30 or 300 MB. People with mobile internet will most likely not waste their limited data volume either way, and unlimited broadband internet people won't notice the difference.

Comment: This isn't for mobile, so that's not a worry. Nonetheless sorry for not following the guidelines. Thanks for the guidance all.

Answer (score 1):

There is multiple setup for build directly in UE4 editor where you can lower the size of files. Current setup you use is probably target for debug. If you choose build for shipping, you will get much smaller files, engine itself is around 47MB, then there is small loader, your game logic (size varies ofc) and your game data (again size varies).

I wouldnt recomend any other third party minification software in case of UE4 engine, not sure if it would be compatible with asm.js magic they use. I belive right now it is as small as it can be, if you consider all the features UE4 engine provides and compare the size to native applications...

Also notice that files are being gziped/bziped for transfer, according to my browser Im transfering 30MB for my app, but total size on disk is ~120MB.

Another thing that might help, start the most empty project and not the project with starter content. It will lower the size for app data.

If you give me few minutes, I might post here some screenshot...

There is first place where you can set build for shipping:
[image]

There is another place:
[image]